# 80s 90s psychic powers anime movie

Tags: story-identification, movie, anime

I'm looking for an anime I watched in the late 80's/early 90's.

There were people with great psychic powers. The main character is a short young-looking guy that is the most powerful of them all. I think he has a blond [Super Saiyan style haircut](https://www.kindpng.com/imgv/iomRJwR_goku-hair-super-saiyan-png-download-transparent-png/) and various psychic powers. He was trying to protect a girl.

I also remember there were schools that trained people with psychic powers and the main bad guy was a female which only appeared as a voice in anybody's​ mind.

Can't say about the network because I live in Greece and it was translated in my language.

Comment: Could it be [Toward the Terra](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Toward_the_Terra), it was also an anime series and a movie. It covers most of the facts that you remember but I don't remember if th computer could speak with peoples voices or not.

Answer (score 3):

Except for the main villain being a woman voice all of the specs fits more or less in the [Akira](https://el.wikipedia.org/wiki/Akira) movie based in the manga from Katushiro Otomo

Comment: Also, no "schools that trained people with psychic powers", unless you count the institute that hid the progerian psychc kids.

Comment: Thats right, ist like a stay, school, train and experiment program , all in one, leaded by the  Colonel Shikishima

Answer (score 2):

Not sure if you are still looking for this, but I've just spent a good 2 days looking for this. Maybe it's *[Locke the Superman](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Locke_the_Superman) - Millennium of the Witch*.

> A quiet, charismatic, lonely immortal esper about which little is known. He is called "Locke the Superman", but often denies being so. It is not known where or when he was born, and if asked, Locke will say he does not remember. It is entirely possible this is true. When he asked by Cornelia Prim in "Millennium of the Witch" which star Locke was from, he replied "Toa." However, it was just the name of the planet where he lived in before.
>
> He has appeared at various times throughout the history of the galaxy, either as a direct influence, an indirect influence, or a simple observer. Using his esper abilities, Locke can learn and do most things more quickly than a normal human. His power also allows him to remain eternally young, or even turn himself into a child again to be adopted by kind-hearted families. This is called "waka-gaeri". It could be said it keeps him young at heart. It is speculated he retains a youthful appearance as an excuse not to take responsibility for whatever cause he is approached for, since no one expects youths to have such responsibilities.

Youtube has one that's Greek dubbed:

Comment: Yes thank very much.
That's the anime I was looking for its Locke the superman